# Application errors with "System.NullReferenceException: Object reference not set to an instance of an object"

Tags: vb.net

I have an application that will not run on one particular Windows 10 machine when it does on another. Both machines are running the same version of Win10 19041.685. The application fails to start, presenting two pages of errors as follows:

```
Custodian 4 has trapped an unhandled error.
System.NullReferenceException: Object reference not set to an instance of an object.
at Custodian4.MDIMain.MDIMain_Load(Object sender, EventArgs e) 
at System.EventHandler.Invoke(Object sender, EventArgs e) 
at System.Windows.Forms.Form.OnLoad(EventArgs e) 
at System.Windows.Forms.Form.OnCreate Control()
at System.Windows.Forms.Control.CreateControl(Boolean flgnore Visible) 
at System.Windows.Forms.Control.CreateControll 
at System.Windows.Forms.Control.WmShowWindow(Message & m) 
at System.Windows.Forms.Control. WndProCMessage & m) 
at System.Windows.Forms.ScrollableControl.Wnd Proc(Message & m) 
at System.Windows.Forms.ContainerControl.Wnd Proc(Message & m) 
at System.Windows.Forms.Form. WmShowWindow(Message& m) 
at System.Windows.Forms.Form.WndProC(Message & m)
at System.Windows.Forms.Control.ControlNativeWindow.OnMessage(Message & m)
at System.Windows.Forms.Control.ControlNativeWindow.Wnd Proc(Message & m)
at System.Windows.Forms.NativeWindow.Callback(IntPtr hWnd, Int32 msg, IntPtr wparam, IntPtr Iparam)

Custodian 4 caught : System.NullReferenceException: Object reference not set to an instance of an object.
at Custodian4.MDIMain.MDIMain_FormClosing(Object sender, FormClosingEventArgs e)
at System.Windows.Forms.Form.OnFormClosing(FormClosingEventArgs e) 
at System.Windows.Forms.Form.RaiseFormClosingOnAppExit 
at System.Windows.Forms.Application.Exitinternall 
at System.Windows.Forms.Application.Exit(CancelEventArgs e) 
at System.Windows.Forms.Application. Exito
at Microsoft.VisualBasic.Application Services.WindowsFormsApplication Base.OnUnhandledException(UnhandledException EventArgs e)
at Microsoft.VisualBasic.Application Services. WindowsFormsApplication Base.OnUnhandledException EventAdaptor(Object sender, ThreadExceptionEventArgs e)
at System.Windows.Forms.Application.ThreadContext.OnThreadException Exception t)
at System.Windows.Forms.Control.Wnd ProcException(Exception e) 
at System.Windows.Forms.Control.ControlNativeWindow.OnThreadExcept ion(Exception e)
at System.Windows.Forms.NativeWindow.Callback(IntPtr hWnd, Int32 msg, IntPtr wparam, IntPtr Iparam) in Custodian4
```

It had been suggested to me that the reason it runs on one machine and not the other is due to an error in the .NET installation. So I have run the .NET Framework Repair Tool (netfxrepairtool.exe) which re-registered a service but the problem remains.

How do I debug this problem further or indeed go about fixing it?

Thanks

Comment: Contact support at http://www.custodian4.co.uk/contact.html ?

Comment: Thank you for the reminder. Sorry, I should have explained that I have had an extended discussion with Custodian4 developer, but since it works on one machine and not another when apparently they are the same Windows build version it suggests there is some error with the Windows 10 or .Net installation. I was rather hoping someone might be able to suggest an approach given the repetitive "System.Windows.Forms" errors. Thanks.

Comment: It does rather remain their problem; I wouldn't accept one of my developers saying "well it doesn't crash on my machine so I told the customer to get stuffed". Ask them for a debug version of the exe that gives line numbers, work with them to get them to debug it. They should be the ones coming here to ask; short of decompiling their exe (which is probably against the terms of the license) we're a bit limited as to what we can do.. They would likely be able to establish remote debugging of the exe on your machine if you push them hard enough. Whether they know how to do so, I don't know

Comment: To clarify, is this an issue of you not being able to run the software provided to you, or an issue of you trying to modify the software and that not working?

Comment: I cannot run the software as provided on one Windows machine but I can on another. The two machines are at the same build of Win10 and have the same Visual C++ versions installed. So we know the software does work, but there is something maybe misconfigured or missing with the Win10 installation that is preventing it running.

Comment: This is really going to be an environmental issue on that pc, probably on the right track with something in the .net framework install.  As Calus suggests, you best bet is working with Custodian support.  If they are un-willing to help, perhaps the next option is to find alternatives to Custodian

Comment: @Hursey I do have the advantage of two Windows 10 machines, one it works on and one that it doesn't. (Its not a long term option to just use the other machine.) Perhaps I need to frame a new question about how to validate/compare a .net framework install?